# Image Grid according to screen width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, gallery

I am writing on a image grid in jquery which will display images in two different sizes. I checked various examples on gallery grids before, but most of them only deal with equal size images.

So the plan is to seperate the images into two sections and accordingly display one row image type one, the other row image type 2.
each row is seperated with a div and gets a class according to the images.
each div is animated to make the images flow into the screen.

I struggle with fitting the image size according to the page width. my plan is to scale one class of images width to 30% page size, the other to 18%, fit the height according to the width and then place the containing div top position according to the image height.

1)I think the width calculated is the original image width and not the 30% of the displayed image. The height obviously is not in proportion 4/3 to the width.

3) I cannot help but think my implementation is way to stiff, got any better idea? I wanted the images to flow into the screen with an animation, so that is why I decided to use absolute position of the divs

I am not new to programming but relatively new to Jquery and JS.

```
   function calcPos(){
    var top1 = 200;
    var top2 = 0;
    var ratio = 4/3;
    var width1 = $('.leftSlide img').first().width();
    var width2 = $('.rightSlide img').first().width();
    var height1 = width1/ratio;
    var height2 = width2/ratio;
    top2 += height1 + top1;

    $( '.leftSlide' ).each(function () {
        $('img').each(function (){
            $(this).attr('height', height1);
            });
        $(this).css({ top: top1 });
        top1 = top1 + height1 + height2;
    });

    $('#back').attr('top', top2);

    $( '.rightSlide' ).each(function () {
        $('img').each(function (){
            $(this).attr('height', height2);
            });
        $(this).css({ top: top2 });
        top2 = top2 + height1 + height2;
    });

    }

$(document).ready(calcPos);
```

the corresponding html just is

```
<div class=leftSlide>
<a href=slide.php?img=1&album=2><img src=images/fashion/1.jpg class=panorama></a>
<a href=slide.php?img=2&album=2><img src=images/fashion/2.jpg class=panorama></a>
<a href=slide.php?img=3&album=2><img src=images/fashion/3.jpg class=panorama></a></div>
<div class=rightSlide>
<a href=slide.php?img=4&album=2><img src=images/fashion/4.jpg class=portrait></a>
<a href=slide.php?img=5&album=2><img src=images/fashion/5.jpg class=portrait></a>
<a href=slide.php?img=6&album=2><img src=images/fashion/6.jpg class=portrait></a>
<a href=slide.php?img=7&album=2><img src=images/fashion/7.jpg class=portrait></a>
<a href=slide.php?img=8&album=2><img src=images/fashion/8.jpg class=portrait></a></div>
```

and the css

```
.portrait{
    width: 18%;
}

.panorama{
    width: 30%;
}
.leftSlide {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    animation: leftSlide 2s;
    z-index: 5;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.rightSlide {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    animation: rightSlide 2s;
    z-index: 5;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```